# WPF DataGrid: Problem with showing DisplayNameAttribute values

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Why WPF DataGrid control doesn't shows defined DisplayNameAttribute values for grid columns? However this works fine when using Winforms DataGridView!

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way in WPF. You could argue it's about maintaining separation of View and Model data.

The easiest way to address your concern is simply defining the column ahead of time; versus setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to true.

```
<toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static const:Resources.ScriptNameHeader_String}" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Comment: I use native wpf DataGrid control, so i think i should use DataGrid control of wpf toolkit. Are you used that? support this?

Comment: @Sadegh I'm on .NET 3.5 SP1 so I am using the WPF Toolkit DataGrid which should be the same DataGrid which was moved into .NET 4. My example should work using the .NET 4 DataGrid AFAIK.

Comment: At the current I'm using .NET 4! My question is about supporting of DisplayName, Browsable and so on; not about your approach. Thanks Aaron

Comment: I'm wonderful why WPF DataGrid doesn't support this functionality! It's not good to define columns by hands! I have up to 30 windows and all of those have their own DataGrid!

Comment: What do you mean define them by hand? They can either be a resource as I have done and thus globally accessed or you can set AutoGenerateColumns to true and not have to set anything.

Comment: My mean of "defining by hands" is declaring each columns and set appropriate resource to each one!

Comment: So I think we have backed to the start point! OK I know that WPF DataGrid doesn't support my goal. Thanks a lot Aaron ;)